# Is there a way to hide an Embarcadero __property already declared in parent?

Tags: c++, properties, overriding, hide, c++builder

I'm using Embarcadero C++Builder compiler. I would like to know if there is a way to hide a property, declared with __property keyword, in a child class.

For example, I'm creating a control derived from TPanel, in which I've overridden the paint function. In my new TDerivedPanel, the Caption property became useless, and I would hide it. It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

Do the same thing that `TPanel` does - derive your component from `TCustomPanel` instead and promote only the `protected` properties that you are interested in.  `Caption` is declared as `protected` in `TControl` but promoted to `__published` by `TPanel`.